# Applying 1 JavaScript syntax for Multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript code to export a table to Excel format.  It works fine with 1 table along with 1 button.

JS

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function TableToExcel()
{
    var id = $('#dvData');
    var strCopy = $('<div></div>').html(id.clone()).html(); window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);
    var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    objExcel.visible = false; var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add; var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1); objWorksheet.Paste; objExcel.visible = true;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table  id="dvData">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Billing System</th>
                        <th>Market Code</th>
                        <th>Payment Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>RED</td>
                        <td>222</td>
                        <td>$103.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BLUE</td>
                        <td>111</td>
                        <td>$13.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GREEN</td>
                        <td>555</td>
                        <td>$143.00</td>  
                    </tr>
                </table>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" onclick="TableToExcel();" />
```

But when I have more than one tables, it seems like the Javascript doesn't work!
First, ID is changed to class like the below code.

Please help!  Thanks

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function TableToExcel()
{
    var class = $('.dvData .dvData1');
    var strCopy = $('<div></div>').html(class.clone()).html(); window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);
    var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    objExcel.visible = false; var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add; var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1); objWorksheet.Paste; objExcel.visible = true;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table  class="dvData">
    <tr>
        <th>Account System</th>
        <th>Market Code</th>
        <th>Payment Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RED</td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>$103.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BLUE</td>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>$13.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>GREEN</td>
        <td>555</td>
        <td>$143.00</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" onclick="TableToExcel();" /> 

<table  class="dvData1">
 <tr>
    <th>Billing System</th>
    <th>Market Code</th>
    <th>Payment Amount</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>RED</td>
    <td>222</td>
    <td>$103.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>BLUE</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>$13.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>GREEN</td>
    <td>555</td>
    <td>$143.00</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" onclick="TableToExcel();" />
```

Comment: Use `var class = $('.dvData, .dvData1');`, to target both. Missing the comma will result in the script looking for a `.dvData1` element nested in a `.dvData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word in javascript. Change the variable name to something valid and select multiple elements by separating them with a comma:

```
var $class = $('.dvData, .dvData1');
```

Here is one solution to get this working the way you expect:

HTML:

```
<table  class="dvData">
    <tr>
        <th>Account System</th>
        <th>Market Code</th>
        <th>Payment Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RED</td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>$103.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BLUE</td>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>$13.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>GREEN</td>
        <td>555</td>
        <td>$143.00</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" class="toExcelButton" data-target="dvData" id="btnExport" value="Export" onclick="TableToExcel();" /> 

<table  class="dvData1">
 <tr>
    <th>Billing System</th>
    <th>Market Code</th>
    <th>Payment Amount</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>RED</td>
    <td>222</td>
    <td>$103.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>BLUE</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>$13.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>GREEN</td>
    <td>555</td>
    <td>$143.00</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" class="toExcelButton" data-target="dvData1" id="btnExport" value="Export" onclick="TableToExcel();" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".toExcelButton").click(function() {
        var table = $("." + $(this).data('target'));
        var strCopy = $('<div></div>').html(table.clone()).html(); window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);
        var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        objExcel.visible = false; 
         var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add; 
        var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1); 
        objWorksheet.Paste; 
        objExcel.visible = true;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan Crowe,  NietzscheProgrammer and Blex very much!  It works now.  When I click on the first button,  it generates the first table, but when I click on second button, it generates the first table, also.  It sounds like it looks for the first class, only.  Any idea?

Comment: Updated the code. This is one solution that should work for your needs. The important bit is being able to tie the button click to a particular table which is being done in this case through the `data-target` attribute on the button

Comment: Thank you very much,  Jonathan Crowe!  Yes, `data-target` is a main key to solve this issue.  It works as expected!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, the same page, I got into another issue, can you please take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352658/jquery-export-to-excel-ie-issue).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first: remove your `var class` and try maybe with `selection` or something because `class` is already a reserved word, then do:

```
var selection = $('.dvData, .dvData1');
```

if you need something else let me know.

Comment: Why post the exact same answer as the one @JonathanCrowe posted 11 minutes ago?